# Regex & BeautifulSoup - TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: regex, beautifulsoup

My code is running into some unexpedt error. Tried to tweak with have 'u' instead of 'r', but still get same error. Tried other solutions from stacks, but didn't go anywhere. Any suggestion?

```
#use urlib and beautifulsoup to scrpe table 

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.example.com/profiles'

page = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
#print(soup)

reEngName = re.compile(r'\[\*\*.+\*\*\]')
reKorName = re.compile(r'\([^\/h]*\)')
reProfile = re.compile(r'\|.+')

for line in re.findall(reEngName, soup):
    print(line)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ckurllib.py", line 18, in <module>
    for line in re.findall(reEngName, soup):
  File "C:\Users\Sammy\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 222, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand everything, but my guess is that in `re.findall(reEngName, soup)` you are providing a `BeautifulSoup` object and findall is expecting a `String`

Comment: You should be able to convert it to string using `re.findall(reEngName, str(soup))`

Comment: @Gawil there is no much point to  use soap for that.. unless they would like to prettify it first or cut out a part page using parameters of soap

Comment: @Swift: I was just trying to figure out his error, not to comment his choices

Comment: @Gawil  basicly  urllib.urlopen(url).read() had returned the text, you can print it or pass to  text processing engine. converting  soap to text result in parting whole html into SOAP structure, then serializing it to plain text. re.findall(reEngName, page) should be enough?

Comment: @Gawil @Swift What would be a good way to find stuff in `beautifulsoup` object? Since use regex on `beautifulsoup` seems to be much easier for what I want to accomplish.

Comment: @Swift `text = str(soup)` would that be sufficient to make it into a string?

Comment: @DatCra: This should be possible directly with the Beautifulsoup library... However I am not aware of all its functionalities ^^ All I can say is read the doc !

Comment: @DatCra: As Swift noticed, Beautifulsoup purpose is parsing html text. If you want to convert it to string afterwards, it does not make much sense... Use the initial text instead ! Anyway, `text = str(soup)` should work fine, yes...

Comment: @DatCra `page` is your text. `urlopen()` returns filehandle,  `read()` fetches the text.SOAP is good if expect to find matches in certain parts of document, avoiding false positives, or editing comments, for example/

Comment: @Gawil I found beautifulsoup text is easier to locate what i wanted, maybe i'll give the original a try as well.

Answer (score 0):

Regex  works with strings. If you want to search  whole raw text of file,  give  the `page` to regex. Soap is a parser, that internally splits html into its syntactic components, organized into a tree, you can iterate through them.  For example, to iterate all `<a>` tags:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
for a in soup('a'):
    out = doThings(a)
```

in doThings(a):

```
if a['href'].startswith("http:///www.domain.net"):
```

Naturally, in latter stage you can use regexes to check for matches in strings.